# Conjunct letters in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, editors

I use TeXstudio as the LaTeX editor. When I write Bengali (which has many [conjunct letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunct_consonant)) using TeXstudio, the conjunct letters are not properly shown. An example of a script containing conjunct letters is here

```
\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{রাসায়নিক বিক্রিয়ার শ্রেণীবিভাগ}
    
    রাসায়নিক বিক্রিয়াগুলোকে নিম্নলিখিত বিষয়গুলোর উপর ভিত্তি করে শ্রেণিবিভাগ করা যায়ঃ
    
    \subsection{রাসায়নিক বিক্রিয়ার দিক}
    বিক্রিয়ার দিকের উপর ভিত্তি করে রাসায়নিক বিক্রিয়াকে দুই ভাগে ভাগ করা যায়। একমুখী বিক্রিয়া ও উভমুখী বিক্রিয়া। 
    \\
    \paragraph{একমুখী বিক্রিয়া}
    যে রাসায়নিক বিক্রিয়ায় বিক্রিয়ক পদার্থগুলো উৎপাদে পরিণত হয়, কিন্তু উৎপাদ পদার্থগুলো পুনরায় বিক্রিয়কে পরিণত হয় না তাকে একমুখী বিক্রিয়া বলা হয়। 
    
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \[ CaCO_{3} (s) \longrightarrow CaO (s) + CO_2 \]
    
\end{document}
```

When I wrote this in TeXstudio, it looks like this:

[image: Portion of tex file from TeXstudio]

Just look at the conjunct letters of the words 'বিক্রিয়া', 'শ্রেণীবিভাগ'. They are just terrible.

Although the output pdf file has no problem with conjunct letters, it will be great if the editor shows the conjunct letters correctly. I have tried changing font at `Options -> Configure TeXstudio` but that didn't work for me. Can you suggest a way for this?

Comment: Since this is a TeXstudio problem it may be a good idea to post an issue on https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues.

Comment: Thanks Marijn. I have posted an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is pretty simple. Just needs to change the font family of the editor to a font that supports conjuncts and that's all.

As  I have mentioned in the question, I tried by changing the font at the `General` tab at `Options -> Configure TeXstudio`. It didn't work, as this action only affects the menu bar:

[image: The result of changing the font to Monotype Corsiva]

In the image, you can see the result of changing the font to Monotype Corsiva.

To change the font of your code, you need to change the font family in the `Editor` tab at `Options -> Configure TeXstudio`.

[image]

As you can see, I have changed the font to Nirmala UI which supports some Indian languages including Bengali. For Bengali, you may also use Kalpurush, Shonar Bangla, SolaimanLipi, or Siyam Rupali.